# Show $2^{10x/7}(1-x) \le \frac12$ for sufficiently small $x>0$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Show  $2^{10x/7}(1-x) \le \frac12$ for sufficiently small $x$, where $x$ is positive.

I've thought about trying to find the limit to this as $x$ tended to $0$, but have had a lot of difficulties. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. 
In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you write what your thoughts 
are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in this and future posts 
and in what context you have encountered the problem; this will prevent people 
from telling you things you already know, 
and help them give their answers at the right level. This site uses [MathJax formatting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: It [turns out](http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E%2810x%2F7%29*%281-x%29<%3D1&x=0&y=0) that $2^{10x/7}(1-x)$ is less than or equal to $1$ for all nonnegative $x$, and actually most of the negative ones too.

Comment: Sorry, i was meant to say less than or equal to 1/2 instead of 1

Comment: The revised statement isn't true.  The function $2^{10x/7}(1-x)$ is continuous, and takes the value $1$ at $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

As Barry Cipra commented, there is something wrong in the problem.

Considering the function $$f(x)=2^{10 x/7} (1-x)$$ $$f'(x)=-\frac{1}{7} 2^{10 x/7} (10 (x-1) \log (2)+7)$$ the first derivative cancels for $x_*=1-\frac{7}{\log (1024)}\approx -0.00988653$ for which $f(x_*)=\frac{7\ 2^{3/7}}{e \log (32)}\approx 1.00005$ and the second derivative test shows that this is a maximum.

Close to $x=0$, a Taylor expansion gives $$f(x)=1+ \left(\frac{10 \log (2)}{7}-1\right)x+ \left(\frac{50 \log ^2(2)}{49}-\frac{10
   \log (2)}{7}\right)x^2+O\left(x^3\right)$$ Close to $x=1$, a Taylor expansion gives $$f(x)= 2^{10/7} (1-x)-\frac{20}{7}  \left(2^{3/7} \log
   (2)\right)(1-x)^2+O\left((x-1)^3\right)$$

In order to have $f(x)\lt \frac 12$, it would be required that $$x>1+\frac{7 }{\log (1024)}W\left(-\frac{5 \log (2)}{14\ 2^{3/7}}\right)\approx 0.76576$$ So, I suppose that the problem is for values of $x$ close to $1$ instead.

Answer (score 0):

to make it clear, the value of $y=2^{(10x/7)}(1-x)$ between $[0,1]$ looks like:

[image]

obviously it's not less than 1/2 for small positive x

by the way, x=0 is where $2^{(10x/7)}(1-x)$ get max value

two roots for $2^{(10x/7)}(1-x)=1/2$ is approximately -1.7049 and 0.76576